# Using NgControl without form container in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have component that wraps input. Is there a way i can use NgControl if there is no parent form present?

Comment: have you tried adding `#f="ngForm"` in the wrapper even if its not a form?

Comment: without form how you can use ngControl ? if you want to get value you can use local variable declared using # in the angular2 like this `#abc`

Comment: i want to build input component that will get control object as @Input. The component will be mainly used in form and there is no problem. But there is cases when the component is used without form. I still can use form but i want to know if my component can be functional without form

Comment: Anyway i solved it by using ngFormControl instead of ngControl.

Comment: Hi Kliment, can you expose us what you did on this, I was trying yo wrap my input component asweel but didn't find the right way to add my input component controls to themain form...

Comment: Hi @JulienAlary. I used `[ngFormControl]` directive and pass new Control object from the class. Also control object can be passed trough @Input() decorator. The definition in the class looks like this `@Input() inputControl: Control = new Control()` and in the template `[ngFormControl]="inputControl"`. If you want to use the input component in a form you do it like this `<input-component [inputControl]="myForm.controls['someControl']"></input-component>`. You must use custom controls if you wanna get this working.

Comment: Thx. I really appreciate.